# Running python Selenium tests on CircleCI

Tags: python, selenium, circleci

I'm trying to run some python selenium tests in the test phase of CircleCI.

My circle.yml looks like this:

```
machine:
  python:
    version: 2.7.9
  node:
    version: 0.10.34
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8
dependencies:
  post:
    - pip install selenium
    - wget http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
    - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar:
        background: true
test:
  post:
    - python /home/ubuntu/app/tests/tests.py
...
```

and tests.py looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://127.0.0.1')

print driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-class').text
```

I have two questions:

First off, how to I output data from test.py back to CircleCI's interface (the print statement obviously doesn't work)

Secondly, what's the correct address to use in the `driver.get()` call, as I get an `http://127.0.0.1/ is not available` error?

Here's the full traceback:

```
http://127.0.0.1/ is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/app/tests/tests.py", line 11, in <module>
    print driver.find_element_by_class_name('yes-cta').text
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/venv-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/venv-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/venv-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/venv-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.130)

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Linux 3.13.0-76-generic x86_64) python /home/ubuntu/app/tests/tests.py returned exit code 1
```

Comment: Presumably you're not waiting for the page to load before performing your lookup, but please supply a trace so we can what the actual error is.

Comment: Edited with traceback.  I'm not sure what to use in the `driver.get` call.

Comment: It's the URL you're trying to test. I doubt you've got a web server running on port 80 on 127.0.0.1...

Comment: Do you know if CircleCI exposes the web server somehow though?  I know they allow some kind of headless browser tests (so they have to be serving it somehow), but I couldn't find exactly how to hook up to that without using the specific testing frameworks they say they support out of the box.

Comment: But surely the reason you want to run a Sel test is that you have a site you want to test, which could be any URL. Surely all CircleCI does is provide a complete Python (+Java) env so that your Sel tests can run. Perhaps there are advanced monitoring capabilities I don't know about, but the only web server will be the one that runs the site you're trying to test. Which, for most newbies, is Google or Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  From http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#remotewebdriver

```
driver.get('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
```

sets it up correctly and standard print statements do work to output results back to CircleCI.